# Converting CIImage coordinates to CGRect from CIFaceFeature

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage, cifacefeature, facial-identification

I am trying to place a square rectangle over a user's face which I am recognizing using `CIFaceFeature` in real time over a full screen (`self.view.frame`) video feed. However, the coordinates I am getting from `CIFaceFeature.bounds` are from a different coordinate system than that used by views. I have tried converting these coordinates from [this](https://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image/) and [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578821/cifacefeature-bounds). But since I don't I am running this atop a video feed I don't have an image I can pass into `CIImage` to ease with the conversion of coordinates. Below is an example of my configuration, any idea how I can convert to a usable `CGRect`?

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let opaqueBuffer = Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer>.passUnretained(imageBuffer!).toOpaque()
    let pixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(opaqueBuffer).takeUnretainedValue()
    let sourceImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    let features = self.faceDetector!.features(in: sourceImage, options: options)

    if (features.count != 0) {
        let faceImage = sourceImage
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
        let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: faceImage) as! [CIFaceFeature]

        let transformScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        let transform = transformScale.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -faceImage.extent.height)
        for feature in features as! [CIFaceFeature] {

            faceBounds = feature.bounds

            var fb = faceBounds?.applying(transform)
            // imageViewSize is the screen frame
            let scale = min(imageViewSize.width / fb!.width,
                            imageViewSize.height / fb!.height)

            let dx = (imageViewSize.width - fb!.width * scale) / 2
            let dy = (imageViewSize.height - fb!.height * scale) / 2

            fb?.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
            fb?.origin.x += dx
            fb?.origin.y += dy

            realFaceRect = fb // COMPLETELY WRONG :'(
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not real familiar with the specific API in question, however, the name "applying" implies that the original object is unmodified and the updated value is returned, and indeed your original usage also implies that.  I'd try replacing `fb?.applying(...)` with `fb = fb?.applying(...)`  But I'd also compute and apply a single transform instead of using 2 transforms and a shift (which is effectively a 3rd transform)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same problem. Here's an easy solution

```
let imgHeight = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))
let ratio = self.view.frame.width / self.visage!.imgHeight

func convertFrame(frame: CGRect, ratio: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let x = frame.origin.y * ratio
    let y = frame.origin.x * ratio
    let width = frame.height * ratio
    let height = frame.width * ratio
    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
}

func convertPoint(point: CGPoint, ratio: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let x = point.y * ratio
    let y = point.x * ratio
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```